# Create react app, reload not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I just started coding in React using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). In the documentation it's said

> The page will reload if you make edits.

I don't know which module is responsible for auto reload (webpack or react-hot-reloader?) but it's not working. I edited file using different editors (Sublime, VIM, ..) but it seems problem is for something else. Any advice how to debug it?

Comment: Are you using `npm start`, or loading it by opening it from the html file. Probably a stupid question, but its worth asking sometimes...

Comment: @BobbyW I'm using npm start

Comment: npm cache clean --force

Comment: I have similar problem with windows. Any solution

Comment: I have a similar problem on Firefox browser but it is working fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After too many searches I found Webpack watch uses inotify to observe file changes and in ubuntu it's set to a low value. a quick fix:

```sh
sudo -i
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
exit
```

If you want change it permanently (from [Ronald answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60724414/846634)):

```sh
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

You may also need to add a `.env` file in the root directory of your project with this line "FAST_REFRESH=false" as noted in [create react app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/).

```sh
echo "FAST_REFRESH=false\n" | cat > .env
```

Comment: within what directory did you run the terminal command above?

Comment: doesn't matter, whenever you are run it

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked in my linux mint. but I need to run this command every time the PC restarts. any way around ?

Comment: It worked on Linux Mint.. and easiest way to solve issue

Answer (score 27):

**Year 2021**

I had this issue in react `^17.0.2` I fixed it by adding a `.env` file and setting `FAST_REFRESH=false`.
Just create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project and add `FAST_REFRESH=false` in the file.

Comment: This does work. Man, it was so frustrating to manually refresh. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu users, run this in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Scroll to the bottom and paste:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Save and close the editor, then run this:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

To check your success:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

This should return 524288

by ***apsrcreatix***

Ref: https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code/issues/29#issuecomment-477126012

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu.

The problem was resolved by deleting **node_modules** and then run

```
yarn install // or npm install
```

Comment: Your solution works for me. In my case, I used `npm i` instead of `yarn install`.

Comment: it reffers to the same thing

Answer (score 4):

I hope to save someone else the same pain I experienced.

I'm using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 WSL, with nvm to manage node/npm.

I had to:

- Use Node v16.14.2 in nvm (which also uses npm 8.5.0)
- Change react-scripts from `"react-scripts": "5.0.0"` to `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"` in my package.json file
- Change my package.json start script to

```
   "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

- I then ran `npm install` to update react scripts and restarted the bash terminal
- I also followed Ronald Araújo's advice in his answer for good measure.

5 hours later, it's finally working!

Good luck everyone!

Comment: This did it for me on WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks John

Comment: I have a similar problem on Firefox browser but it is working fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

There **actually is solution** to get **Fast refresh** working.

Use this patch https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11105/files
From @pmmmwh

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package for editing your dependencies.

1. install `patch-package` (via npm or yarn into your project)

   - npm: `npm i patch-package`
   - yarn: `yarn add patch-package postinstall-postinstall`
2. Edit `package.json` and add `postinstall` script

   ```
   "scripts": {
   +  "postinstall": "patch-package"
   }
   ```
3. Edit file `YOUR_PROJECT/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js` - with changes introduced in github pull request above
4. run `npx patch-package react-dev-utils`
5. commit changes created by this script (e.q. `./patches/react-dev-utils+11.0.4.patch`)
6. run your app, now it will refresh on changes

Or wait for new release of `react-dev-utils` (it is not yet released, last version `@11.0.3` **doesn't** contain this update).

Answer (score 0):

My hot reload in Create React app broke due to updating some packages (probably because of `typescript`). I had to solve it without the ejecting of CRA.

**I managed to fix it by upgrading to version 16.10 of these packages:**

```
"react": "^16.10.0",
"react-dom": "^16.10.0"
```

And it worked just fine!

My code in `index.tsx`:

```
...
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootEl)

if (isDev && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('screens/App', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootEl)
  })
}
```

**Hint:**
First try just this code (maybe you are setting wrong path)

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

If this start working then you want to specify the path in order to make hot loading more effective (less bubbling = shorter loading)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` in a .env file.

Answer (score -1):

After create-react-app,I change my project's name.This is one of reasons which make reload not working.Then I create-react-app again,reload is working now.

Answer (score -1):

If the React webpage is not reloading upon saving changes, try adding this line to the **App.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by creating my React app inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) folder, instead of creating it in any Windows directory.