# Hot Reload is not working in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I have created this app with npx create-react-app. After this i have deleted all the files except index.js in src folder. Then Hot reload is not working. I have go to chrome and manually refreshing the page for see changes.
This is my **index.js** file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

function Greeting() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello World</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Click Here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDom.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This does happen sometimes. Do npm install and try adding some code. Then do CTRL+S and check whether the page is updating

Comment: Refresh the editor, restart npm, clear cache of your website in the browser and some more steps here and there. Should be fine

Comment: You have React-17. Do one thing do these updates in your package.json() and then do npm install,                                                                                                              "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create react app, reload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189575/create-react-app-reload-not-working)

Answer (score 19):

To solve the problem in hot reloading/fast_refresh I simply add **CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true** in *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start", //add this line
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem on WSL Ubuntu version 2

Comment: In react-scriptsV5.0.0+ its now `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73862566/901311

Comment: For React v18.4.* with wsl version2 works that solution.

Comment: `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` worked for me on wsl2 Ubuntu in mounted directory

Comment: Here from Windows 11 + Ubuntu WSL2 and this works!

Answer (score 15):

There was an issue - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904

 
A workaround is putting below code in index.js to enable reloading

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

you must restart your server after making this change

Answer (score 14):

While the above solutions are also beneficial, One other way that worked for most people is creating a `.env` folder in your Project.

And use the following Property there.

```
FAST_REFRESH = false
```

[image]

After you add the above, you got to restart your server

Answer (score 8):

This could be **due to your filesystem, file extensions or the Create-React-App default webpack/project configuration**. You don't necessarily have to change all of this because hot-reloading is supposed to work out of the box, and more so if the project has just started.

For example, I once had an issue with a Typescript installation(^17.0.1) where some **files with extension .ts** will not trigger hot reloading. I had to change to **.tsx** and add a React import. The **same could happen with** **.js** and .jsx files.

In case of problems with your filesystem (Unix, Mac) you can try the React config **(FAST_REFRESH=false)** [here...](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) or changing folder names, but I haven't bumped much into this.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! After initializing with `create-react-app`, then I just renamed `App.js` to `App.jsx`. Now it is hot-reloading.

Comment: This is  a good solution. Thank you. But what if the faulty file is the autogenerated react-app-env.d.ts? Do I even need this?

Answer (score 4):

There were a problem with react-scripts version 4.0.1 in package.json file.
I have replaced it with 'react-scripts' : '3.4.4' and Now its working.
for more info: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9984

Answer (score 4):

If your page is not loading automatically then you have to do these steps:

1. add `.env` file
2. add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` in `.env` file

Answer (score 1):

There is a hot reloading issue for some browsers, with react version 17.

Below is the simplest way to fix this:

- Go to `package.json` and replace react, `react-dom` and `react-scripts`
  dependencies with below:

  ```
  "react": "^16.13.1"  
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1"  
  "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  ```
- Delete the `node_modules` folder.
- Run `npm install` (It will install all the dependencies again)
- Start your CRA project with `npm start`

This will fix the hot reloading issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change your file `index.js` to `index.jsx`. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just incase you've tried everything with no solution, make sure you're working on your computer's drive and not saving your project on an external drive. This was my issue, I simply moved the project to my computer's drive and it worked perfectly. Happy coding guys!

Comment: I'd like to understand why this would be an issue, but this is exactly what was happening to me.  I use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as my main shell, but typically keep all my projects in C:\projects and create a symlink from /projects -> /mnt/c/projects.  This was keeping hot reloading from working.  Once I moved the projects to a folder on the WSL filesystem then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried every solution suggested in these comments and nothing worked for me. I was following a tutorial that used `react-router-dom@5.1`. Nothing worked at all including both `.env` suggestions, the `react-scripts` suggestion, or the `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` suggestion. I even switched between npm and yarn to see if one or the other was causing the issue.

The only thing that worked for me was using `yarn add react-router-dom` for the latest version without any specific version attached, and instead of a `Switch` using the new `Routes` component [listed in the version 6 quick start](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview). Now it works great with zero issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hot reload issue when chrome downloaded the update but didn't install it.
After installing the update, all problems disappeared

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem using `wsl2` with `Ubuntu-22.04` and I solve it by moving my project from my mounted windows drive (`/mnt/c`) to `/home` directory into my wsl distro. Once done, it work perfectly and much faster !

To do it with your windows file explorer, you can found your distro files under `\\wsl$` path. So basically for me it was under `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home`.

I've found this solution through this thread https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10253#issuecomment-940654613

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggestions above but not working.
Finally I've found that the reason is because of some eslint rules are violated and make the application **Failed to Compile**.

After I fix the rules in `eslintrc.json` it works

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the above helped me, as soon as i was running dev server on `wsl 22.02`. But when i started it with `git bash`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the react-script version to 4.0.3 inside package.json
2. Add this to package.json below the dependencies
   "resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" },
3. Install react-error-overlay v6.0.9 inside your devDependencies
4. Remove node_modules & package-lock.json
5. Do npm install and check that works.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem when I was implementing the code in my `.env` file

Go into your `.env` file and paste this line:

```
FAST_REFRESH = false
```

It should be working for hot reloading your application when you save the file code.